# How to remove first char of every line in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have c# project with RichTextBox and every line start with some number, but I need to remove that number, so I need to remove first char of every line of that RichTextBox.

it might also have a blank line somewhere.

Example:

> 1H|\^&|||XS^00-20^69652^^^^05342311||||||||E1394-97
>   32
>   2P|1|||4422/12/17|^Turinawe^ROBERT||19831013|M|||||||||||||||||^^^MHC
>   54
>   3C|1
>   33

I need:

> H|\^&|||XS^00-20^69652^^^^05342311||||||||E1394-97
>   2
>   P|1|||4422/12/17|^Turinawe^ROBERT||19831013|M|||||||||||||||||^^^MHC
>   4
>   C|1
>   3

I tried this code and similar but no success

```
var  linije = txtStatus.Lines;
for (int i = linije.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  var thisLineStart = txtStatus.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
  var maxLines = txtStatus.Lines.Count();
  if (i >= maxLines)
  {
    txtStatus.Text = txtStatus.Text.Remove(thisLineStart);
  }
  else
  {
    var nextLineStart = txtStatus.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i + 1);
    txtStatus.Text = txtStatus.Text.Remove(thisLineStart, nextLineStart - thisLineStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: See the TrimLeftLine function in my post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lines collection already gives you the positions you want, so just use that:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in txtStatus.Lines) {
  if (s.Length > 0) {
    sb.AppendLine(s.Substring(1));
  }
}
txtStatus.Text = sb.ToString();
```

If your numbers enter the two digit range or more, then you would have to start checking the individual characters until you get to a non-integer.

Comment: Like all other answers you are chaging the Text thereby messing up formatting.

Comment: @TaW This looks like it's part of some kind of EDI or HL7 document, so formatting wouldn't usually be an issue.  The question is clearly not about formatting.  Can't say I agree with your duplicate choice.

Comment: Well if formatting is not needed why chose a richtextbox? you can always add other anwers but mine contains a TrimLeftLine function that does directly what op asked..

Comment: I work's, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with a generic `List<string>` here since I'm on a Console app, but the idea here is the same. You iterate through lines, and replace each line with a `Substring` that starts at the `index=1`.

```
var lines = new List<string>
{
    @"1H|\^&|||XS^00-20^69652^^^^05342311||||||||E1394-97 2",
    @"2P|1|||4422/12/17|^Turinawe^ROBERT||19831013|M|||||||||||||||||^^^MHC 4",
    @"3C|1 3"
};

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    lines[i] = lines[i].Substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Linq, you can use `Select`.
The Linq counterpart to Sach's answer would be:

```
lines = lines.Select(line => line.Substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying some other workaround:

```
var lines = txtStatus.Lines;
test.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToList().ForEach((line)=> 
    {
        line = line.Substring(1);
    });
```